# Date Time Formatter use same pattern but different output with similar date string format

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

I have multiple files which contains many date time strings.
Example :

File 1 :
string date = 30 Nov 2023, 18:15:53
format = dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss
result => success formatted (2023-11-30T22:46:48)

File 2 :
string date = 10 Dec 2023, 20:23:53
format = dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss
result => Text '10 Dec 2023, 20:23:53' could not be parsed at index 3

```
DateTimeFormatter dFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatDate);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, dFormatter);
```

Why does it produce different results ? And how do I solve this ?

Comment: That string can be parsed by that format. There must be some other characters in there that are not apparent to the eye. Tabs? Zero-width spaces? Non-breaking spaces? You need to check to see exactly what the string contains.

Comment: What is the current locale? Is "Dec" a valid month in the current locale's language?

Comment: @Sweeper good call, I didn't think of that. Also for OP, to check the contents of the string you could do `dateTimeString.codePoints().mapToObj(Character::getName).forEach(System.out::println)` or collect them in a list for logging, etc.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you, you are right, it was the locale. Someone set it to non EN on a project level. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @DavidConrad apparently there's no special character involved. The issue was locale. Thank you for responding as well.

Answer (score 3):

## Locale

When parsing localized formats such as yours, a `Locale` object determines the human language and cultural norms used in translating name of month, punctuation, etc.

If you choose to not specify a `Locale`, the JVM’s current default locale is used implicitly. If you have a specific locale in mind, I suggest **always specifying that `Locale` object explicitly** rather than rely upon the default.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern( "dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss" )
        .withLocale( locale ) ;  // ⬅️ Specify locale.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

The ideal solution would be educating the publisher of your data about using only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time values as text. Localized formats should be used only for presentation to the user, never for data storage nor data exchange.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2023-12-10T20:23:53" ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Comment: Good suggestion! Alternatively, one can use  [`DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(String pattern, Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-).

Answer (score 0):

Locale matters but you can also use `parseCaseInsensitive();`

```
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
    builder.parseCaseInsensitive();
    builder.appendPattern(formatDate);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```